# Rails 4 - Ransack usage with nested resources on parent show page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, ransack

So in my app a Client has many sites, my routes and controller are nested under clients and they all appear on the show page (code below).

What I am trying to acheive is implimenting a Ransack search form and sort links on the clients show page so a user can search the associated sites ect.

Currently when I create the site that is associated to the client it displays ALL Sites across all clients no matter what client a site is associated to.

my routes:

```
  resources :clients, controller: 'clients' do
    resources :sites, controller: 'clients/sites', except: [:index]
  end
```

client controller /show action

```
 class ClientsController < ApplicationController 
      def show
        @client = Client.find(params[:id])

        @q = Site.ransack(params[:q])
        @sites = @q.result(distinct: true).page(params[:page]).per(5)
      end
end
```

My models:

```
class Client < ApplicationRecord
 has_many :sites, dependent: :destroy
end 

class Site < ApplicationRecord
 belongs_to :client
end
```

My search form and sort links on the Clients/show[:id] page

```
<%= search_form_for @q do |f| %>
 <%= f.search_field :site_ident_or_site_name_cont, :class => 'form-control', :placeholder => 'search client...' %>
<% end %>

<%= sort_link(@q, :site_name, 'Site Name') %>
```

what I want to do is to only search the sites associated to the client being displayed. Any assistance here would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the solution was a 2 part solution thanks to Taryn East's answer above for getting the ball rolling for me!

the controller action dose need to be scoped like she had suggested like so:

```
  def show
    @client = Client.find(params[:id])

    # scope by just the sites belonging to this client
    @q = @client.sites.ransack(params[:q])
    @sites = @q.result(distinct: true).page(params[:page]).per(5)
  end
```

then a few modifications to the search form:

```
<%= search_form_for @q, url: client_path(params[:id]) do |f| %>
 <%= f.search_field :site_name_cont, :class => 'form-control', :placeholder => 'search client...' %>
<% end %>
```

This fixed the problem

Answer (score 2):

I am unfamiliar with ransack, but I'd be guessing you should use the association to scope the search eg:

```
  def show
    @client = Client.find(params[:id])

    # scope by just the sites belonging to this client
    @q = @client.sites.ransack(params[:q])
    @sites = @q.result(distinct: true).page(params[:page]).per(5)
  end
```

Comment: So with that I am getting {NoMethodError at /clients/1
undefined method `sites_path' for #<#<Class:0x007f863be58a58>:0x007f863ca6adc8>
Did you mean?  asset_path}

Comment: Ok so I figured it out! Your post got me going there were some changes to the search form that needed to be done too. Thanks for your help!